# wxWidgets and Dev-C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, dev-c++

I've been using Bloodshed Dev-C++ for C++ programing for a while now. I'd like to get into GUI programing in C++. So I installed wxWidget and tried a simple [hello world program](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hworld.txt), yet I get the following error:

```
\Dev-Cpp\gui_at0.cpp C:\Dev-Cpp\C wx/wx.h: No such file or directory.
```

I'm pretty sure this error is due to the wx folder not being in the right directory. Currently it's in C:. So where does it need to be moved to? Or is something else at play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uff, long time since I worked with Dev-C++, but basically you need to tell your compiler where to find the wxWidgets library. It should be somewhere around `Compiler Options -> Include Directories` or the likes. [Also see here.](http://www.bloodshed.net/faq.html#5) If you can't find those options, another way to get it working is to copy the wxWidgets library to the include paths mentioned in the FAQ.
IIRC there even is a Dev-C++ version with directly integrated wxWidgets.